# Address of attachement via apex

Tags: apex

I have problem with access to the Attachemnt.

I try use;

```
<img src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + logoId" />
```

but I have problem.

I see - this request is to: `https://myDomainTest.cs83.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P4E000001hNatUAE`

but when I use manualy: `<img src="https://myDomainTest--c.cs83.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P4E000001hNatUAE" />`  this working property. 
How get this address  ...**myDomainTest--c.cs83.content.force.com**... via apex because I am able to get only id.

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the domain URL using the following:

```
String baseUrl = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
```

Appending baseUrl to your image tag would look like

```
<img src="baseUrl + '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + logoId" />
```

Comment: No, no - this System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() - return me https://myDomainTest.cs83.force.com/... but I need https://myDomainTest--c.cs83.content.force.com/...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to hardcode the path, you can generate the link using URLFOR() and the [$Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action.htm) global variable.

```
<img src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, att.Id)}"/>
```

Or

```
<img src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, '00Pi000000s2kw3')}"/>
```

Comment: I using Lightning Component with custom controller. 
This is no working for me ;/